# Server Won't Ping Outside Network

Tags: networking

I just installed Server 12.04 onto a spare desktop.  Everything is working well except when I try to ssh using my external ip address.

My /ect/network/interfaces file:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        network 192.168.0.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

I have tried to use dhcp as well, but still no luck.  I know the server can connect to the outside because it can update, but when I try to ping an outside ip address I receive no response packets. I've run older ubuntu servers before, but I've never ran into this problem.  I can ssh in using my internal ip addresses, so normally I would think it was a problem with port forwarding, but because of the lack of response pings I think it is a configuration error.

Comment: If your server can otherwise connect to the outside (updates, browsing, etc.) *but* cannot ping, your router/firewall may be blocking ICMP (ping's protocol) but allowing the standard HTTP which is used for updates, etc.

Comment: you ever get anywhere with this OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize two different problems from your description

1. You cannot establish an `SSH` connection from any external IP address to your server
2. Once logged on to the server (from internal network) you still cannot ping an external IP address **from** the server.

Since you mention port-forwarding and show a private IP on your server it appears that there is NAT/NAPT in action.

The reasons for out-going ping failure and inbound `SSH` connect failures could be different

1. `ping` may be blocked (even at the NAT configuration)
2. Inbound connections need to be forwarded through NAT

   - your inbound `SSH` problems may be of this kind
   - lack of this configuration will not stop outbound translation and connectivity
3. have you tried `telnet www.google.com 80` ? or to some other simple HTTP site?
4. This Serverfault question on [ping over TCP](https://serverfault.com/q/14376/4721) my be of interest.

Comment: I realized today after trying to update I was wrong.  When I attempt to use the static IP instead of dhcp it won't connect to update. Any ideas what could be wrong with my static configuration?